# Connect Power BI to MOCO Web API with Authentication

Tags: authentication, curl, powerbi

I am trying to connect Power BI to MOCO Web API

MOCO provides following curl to get all activities data and also API Key

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://{domain}.mocoapp.com/api/v1/activities?from=2018-06-01&to=2018-06-30&project_id=4242' \
  -H 'Authorization: Token token=YOUR_API_KEY'
```

I am using advanced dialog windows in Power BI Query.

There I provide:

URL parts - https://.mocoapp.com/api/v1/activities?from=2021-01-15&to=2021-01-16
HTTP request header paramethers - ApiKeyName: <My API KEY>

I get an error:

> "We could not authenticate with credentials provided.

Where should I insert API Key?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Get data from Web* and there the *Advanced Option*.

You have two field below the *HTTP reuest header parameters (optional)*

In the *URL Parts* post your link like *https://{domain}.mocoapp.com/api/v1/projects*

In the left field write *Authorization* and in the right field write *Token token={enteryourtokenhere}*

Then the connection will be established.

Greeting and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passed your header keys with this request. Currently your request header key is `Authorization` and the value is `Token token=YOUR_API_KEY`.

Check this request with `postman` or `curl request in terminal` for the debugging then you test with your tool